# C++11 and if(integer)

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++11

Is it still valid and good practice in C++11 write if clause like

```
int i;
//some code
if (i) //some code
```

or it is preferred to write

```
if(i != 0)
```

Comment: Why be less explicit and less self-explanatory if you can at all help it? Especially in cases of very little effort.

Comment: @GrantThomas: If the integer is a pointer or holds a pointer value, if (i) is common shorthand for if(i != nullptr), i.e. if i "exists".  In this case I think the shorthand actually is more abstract and intuitive than the long form.  I do agree, however, that in 99% of other cases this is not the ideal form - better to be more explicit.

Comment: In the end C++11 doesn't change anything in this regard. Whatever you found good practice for good reasons before, keep at it for the same reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well-defined behaviour, so you can use the shorter expression. It might seem cryptic for a non-experienced developer, but regulars shouldn't have problems in understanding it.

It might have some sense to use the longer form when explicitly treating `i` as a number, and omitting it when it has some other logical meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid to use integral POD types as a conditional expression.

I do not think there are any requirements in C++11 to use one style over the other.

Thus, choose whichever style you prefer.